# Find min values within a document using elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

We tried aggregation it is returning the min of all the documents.

Is there any way we can find the min of start date from each document, like this using elasticsearch?.

The output should be "1989-03-01T00:00:00Z" :

```
{
"experience": [{
        "isCurrent": false,
        "endDate": "2000-06-01T00:00:00Z",
        "jobTitle": "a",
        "company": "a",
        "title": "a",
        "startDate": "1996-05-01T00:00:00Z"
    }, {
        "isCurrent": false,
        "endDate": "2012-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "jobTitle": "b",
        "company": "B",
        "title": "b",
        "startDate": "2008-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    }, {
        "isCurrent": false,
        "endDate": "2007-10-01T00:00:00Z",
        "company_org": "",
        "jobTitle": "c",
        "company": "C",
        "companyUrl": "",
        "title": "c",
        "startDate": "2004-09-01T00:00:00Z"
    }, {
        "isCurrent": false,
        "endDate": "1993-03-01T00:00:00Z",
        "jobTitle": "d",
        "company": "D",
        "title": "d",
        "startDate": "1991-05-01T00:00:00Z"
    }, {
        "isCurrent": false,
        "endDate": "1991-05-01T00:00:00Z",
        "company_org": "",
        "jobTitle": "e",
        "company": "E",
        "companyUrl": "",
        "title": "e",
        "startDate": "1989-03-01T00:00:00Z"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Can you share the mapping of the `experience` field? Is it of type `nested`?

Comment: If we have nested mapping for experience can we get the min value of startDate within document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `experience` field has the `nested` data type, then you can retrieve what you expect with the following query that leverages [`nested` `inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits):

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "experience",
      "query": {
        "query_string": { "query": "*" }
      },
      "inner_hits": {
        "size": 1,
        "sort": { "startDate": "asc" }
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

This is going to get you the document with the `experience` having the oldest `startDate`

Comment: When I try to use the above command I get the following error: [nested] query does not support [match_all]",